# Flask Javascript Json Data - Undefined

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I did have this code working a few years ago and have recently come back to it,  i have a javascript refreshing data on a web page.  Im calling the server using json and receiving back what i think is ok.

My python database code, which seems to work fine.

```
    cur = db.execute('select sensor_name, temp from cur_temps ORDER BY sensor_name')
    return jsonify(cur.fetchall())
```

Received Json

```
[["BoilerRoom",24.94],["Cylinder1",49.94],["Cylinder2",42.38],["Cylinder3",41.88],["Sensor1",85],["SolidFuelFlow",59],["SolidFuelReturn",41.62]]
```

Im trying to get the number thats associated with Cylinder2 = 42.38

My js code that worked previously is as follows

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function get_temps() {
    $.getJSON("_status",
            function (data) {

                $('#CylTop').text(data.Cylinder1 + "°")
                $('#CylMid').text(data.Cylinder2 + "°")
                $('#CylBot').text(data.Cylinder3 + "°")
                $('#Solid_flow').text(data.SolidFuelFlow)
                $('#Solid_return').text(data.SolidFuelReturn)
                $('#BRoom').text(data.BoilerRoom);
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data.Cylinder1)
            }

    );

}
setInterval('get_temps()', 5000);
</script>
```

The console shows the (data) fine in the browser, its when i try and show anything else.  ' console.log(data.Cylinder1) ' that shows undefined.
Im a newbie so im assuming some indexing needs to happen as its a array but im a bit lost.
Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

C Dabbs

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be accessing the properties in the `data` as an object. As per the response, it is an array inside an array. So you will have to flatten it before accessing it the way you have it.

```js
function get_temps() {
  $.getJSON("_status",
    function(data) {
      let flattendData = data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        return Object.assign({}, acc, {
          [item[0]]: item[1]
        });
      }, {});

      $('#CylTop').text(flattendData.Cylinder1 + "°")
      $('#CylMid').text(flattendData.Cylinder2 + "°")
      $('#CylBot').text(flattendData.Cylinder3 + "°")
      $('#Solid_flow').text(flattendData.SolidFuelFlow)
      $('#Solid_return').text(flattendData.SolidFuelReturn)
      $('#BRoom').text(flattendData.BoilerRoom);
      console.log(flattendData)
      console.log(flattendData.Cylinder1)
    }

  );

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response it sent me on the right path :),  i done a bit more reading up and converted it in python, when you convert it to json a list becomes a json array and a dict becomes json object.

Comment: @craigdabbs Glad to have helped